# SIGABRT on iPhone but not simulator

Tags: iphone, sigabrt

My IPhone app is suddenly giving a SIGABRT error message when I attempt to run it on my iPhone, before even the first line of the application delegate is reached. It runs fine in the simulator, and even restoring previously working snapshots give the same error when I attempt to load the application on the device.

I fiddled with the Product Name build setting and the data model prior to the problem occurring, but as mentioned, old snapshots that ran fine now won't load, suggesting that the problem isn't in the code.

I have tried restarting xCode, the computer, the iPhone and deleting the app but the problem is still occurring.

I am sure that the problem lies with the device

Any ideas what the problem might be or how I can fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to entirely remove the app in question from the device? When saying removing, I do not mean replacing with an older / same version. Remove it, then install it freshly.

Comment: Yes... Deleted it in the normal way. Updated my question with that info

Comment: Hmm, tough issue then - and fortunately not common. Sorry, the only option I see now is restoring the device entirely (reinstall iOS/backup).

Comment: By that do you mean resetting the device in Settings,or is there something even deeper? How annoying...

Comment: I am not sure if resetting the settings has any effect on your app. The only thing I am certain that does do a "cleansweep" is a restore using the iTunes restoring feature (which effectively reinstalls iOS).

Comment: Are you running via the serial cable?  If not, try that and post what your console says about the SIG.  Also, turn on an "all exceptions" breakpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking on Till's suggestions I reinstalled iOS (well, actually I updated it to 5.1) and everything is working again. Thanks for the advice. I've no idea what went wrong, but at least its working again now!